# Custom field name not showing in Filebeat

Tags: elastic-stack, filebeat, log-analysis

Below is how im trying to add a custom fiels name in my filebeat 7.2.0
filebeat.inputs:

```
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - D:\Oasis\Logs\Admin_Log\*
    - D:\Oasis\Logs\ERA_Log\*
    - D:\OasisServices\Logs\*
  processors:
- add_fields:
     fields:
     application: oasis
```

and with this, im expecting a new field called `application` whose data entries will be `'oasis'`.
But i dont get any.
I also tried

```
 fields:
    application: oasis/'oasis'
```

Help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a customized field for every log, you should put the "fields" configuration in the same level of *type*. Try the following:

```
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - D:\Oasis\Logs\Admin_Log\*
    - D:\Oasis\Logs\ERA_Log\*
    - D:\OasisServices\Logs\*
  fields.application: oasis
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Im not even able to start the application as a windows service.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to add custom fields on filebeat, using the `fields` option and using the `add_fields` processor.

To add fields using the `fields` option, your configuration needs to be something like the one below.

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log 
  paths:
    - 'D:/path/to/your/files/*'
  fields:
    custom_field: 'custom field value'
  fields_under_root: true
```

To add fields using the `add_fields` processor, you can try the following configuration.

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log 
  paths:
    - 'D:/path/to/your/files/*'
processors:
- add_fields:
    target: ''
    fields:
      custom_field: 'custom field value'
```

Both configurations will create a field named `custom_field` with the value `custom field value` in the root of your document.

The `fields` option can be used per input and the `add_fields` [processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.2/filtering-and-enhancing-data.html) is applied to all the data exported by the filebeat instance.

Just remember to pay attention to the **indentation** of your configuration, if it is wrong filebeat won't work correctly or even start.

Comment: Hi @leandrojmp, Aplogies for responding late, i have tried the processors part and i still see no update, should i clear the old index as well?